# how to force user to select an item from gridview

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, gridview

- i have a gridview
- i am working on VS2008 ASP.Net forms

Currently, my update statement does not work unless the user selects an item from the gridview. How do i ensure that the user clicks on 1 before the update is executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of : [GridView.SelectedIndex Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindex.aspx)  - Gets or sets the index of the selected row in a GridView control.

Comment: Thank you! But how may i check if the user does not click on an item @ the gridview then?